# How to click on python object contains onclick attribute in <tr> tag

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working from the following html code :

```
<table .... >
  <tbody .... >
    <tr style="cursor:hand" onclick="OpenSession ("xxxx", "yyyyy", "zzzz")">
       ...
    </tr>
    <tr style="cursor:hand" onclick="OpenSession ("aaaa", "bbbbb", "cccc")">
       ...
    </tr>
  </tbody
</table>
```

With python's selenium library, I want to click on the `tr` tag. I wrote the following code :

```
tr_elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,value='tr')
for tr in tr_elements:
  if tr.get_attribute('onclick'):
    print(tr)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr[contains(@onclick, 'OpenSession ')]"))).click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

When running this script, I get the following error :

> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="96f27c0a-2870-4011-8668-abbbdab5bd2c", element="7a4f8c92-f571-471e-ad63-6c6113f17494")>
> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't give the website it is hard to tell.

I am guessing the element is out of view in the page. You can start by trying to maximise the window and headless mode like this, add the code below at the start of your script.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: @anarchie: Thank you for your reply. In order not to overload the post, I have already taken these elements into account in my python script since it displays the element on which I must click

Comment: @ChristopheC. are you able to share the website?

Comment: Unfortunately not because there is a lot of confidential information

Comment: can you try this `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", tr)`, add it before your for loop

Comment: The command is executed but there is no change in the emulation

Comment: I solved the problem by clicking on the td tag contained in the tr tag with the command : WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[contains(@onclick, 'OpenSession ')]/td[2]"))).click()

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that find out all the elements and then iterate.
When click on the clickable element the page will refreshed and element won't be attached with the DOM and you might get stale reference exception.

Best way to do that to assigned back the elements again.

Try this coe.

```
tr_elements=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//tr[contains(@onclick, 'OpenSession ')]")

for tr in range(len(tr_elements)):
   tr_elements=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//tr[contains(@onclick, 'OpenSession ')]")
   tr_elements[tr].location_once_scrolled_into_view
   tr_elements[tr].click()
   time.sleep(3) # slow down the for loop
```

The will identify all `tr` elements with `onclcick` attribute and then `iterate` and then search the `element` again. it will use index to use `each element` and then `scroll first` and then `click`, once clicked on any element page will `refreshed` and then it will capture the element again in the loop where it is `assined`.